# Can mangaka change their avatar?

Tags: mangaka

Can mangaka change their avatar? Like, what happened if they don't like their avatar anymore and they want to change?

I did try my best to search if they did, but I can't find anyone who did. The closest I found is their art style changes, but nothing about their avatar.

Comment: Their avatar where? On their social media profile? On their table of contents in where they are serialized? On their cover flap of volume release? In their fan site? Artist credits? They probably. Ould pending approval from the editorial staff... It's thier image after all

Comment: In there manga in author note